# Colocar um site com laravel no AWS EC2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-aws

Bom sou novo neste tipo de ambiente estou precisando colocar um website online no Amazon Web Service EC2 porem não estou conseguindo.

Ja tentei alterar o documento `000-default.conf` para a pasta `/www/public` que é a pasta publica de meu documento, porém nada funcionou, a página fica em branco.

Todos programas necessario ja estão instalados e devidamente configurados:

```
Apache2
MySql
PHP7.0
entre outros..
```

O que preciso configurar para quando acessar meu host eu consiga acessar meu site?

[Meu endereço](http://35.166.102.223/) onde eu acesso o site e tem meus arquivos em laravel.

Quais os passo que preciso fazer para funcionar ?

Comment: O servidor é Linux ? Aqui não está nem pingando esse IP.

Comment: Mais quando entro ele acessa as pastas, agora que fiz uma alteração tentando solucionar o problema, eu coloquei para pasta padrao do apache2 ser a pasta public do laravel. Esta dando acesso negado.

Comment: de acesso as pastas e principalmente storage 
use: chmod -R 775 /path/to/your/project